# Set header background Vaadin 14 grid

Tags: java, grid, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am trying to set a background color to the header in a Vaadin 14 Grid.
But I really have no clue how it may work.

This is my code sofar:

```
grid = new Grid<Room>();
```

I probably have to do some

```
@CssImport(themeFor = "vaadin-grid", value = "./styles/grid-header.css")
```

and access some Shadow DOM elements within grid-header.css, but I just can't figure out how it works.

So, does anybody know, how so set the background color of the header of a grid in Vaadin 14 ?

thanks for any help!
Thorsten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the header background for all your grid you can add this in your grid-header.css:

```css
[part~="header-cell"] {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

If you want a specific background, you can add a classname to your grid:

```java
grid.addClassName("background-example");
```

And use this CSS:

```css
:host(.background-example) [part~="header-cell"] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your setup looks correct. What remains is the CSS. Try this:

```css
[part~="header-cell"] {
  background-color: var(--lumo-primary-color);
  color: var(--lumo-primary-contrast-color);
}
```

You can of course use whatever colors you like.

In case you hadn’t already found it, here’s more documentation about how to style the internals of components: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/styling-components

Comment: That solutions works perfectly! Thank you very much. But just an additional question: I set the css to   [part~="header-cell"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: red; 
}      So, foreground color is red, background black. But how can I set the color what the header is active, when the user clicks on it for sorting? Right now the color when active is blue, how may I change it ?